# My Ubuntu 20.04 keeps freezing after logging in

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, acer

I have Acer Predator Helios 300 with Intel i5 Gen 8, 16 GB DDR4 RAM and Nvidia Graphics card model GTX 1060 6GB Mobile.
None of key work after it freezes, not even ALT+CTL+F# or ALT+F#. Please help me out here.

Comment: Does it freeze right from installation, or after some update? Are you using the proprietary drivers by NVidia, or the free and open source drivers?

Comment: It was freezing after usage. It has been few days since i installed it. I was using open source nvidia drivers with gnome desktop. I switched to kde and now it is not freezing